# sound not playing in gridview

Tags: java, android, audio, gridview

i'm triyng to create an app which plays sound on image click in android grid view. I have written some code but the sound does not play. Here is my main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
tools:context="cf.droiddev.animalsoundskids.MainActivity" >

<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
   package cf.droiddev.animalsoundskids;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
   import android.media.MediaPlayer;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
   import android.widget.GridView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                String filename="sound_" + Integer.toString(position) + ".wav";
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(filename); 
                if(afd != null) {
                    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

And Here is ImageAdapter.java

```
package cf.droiddev.animalsoundskids;

import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.alligator, R.drawable.bear,
        R.drawable.cat, R.drawable.cattle,
        R.drawable.chickens, R.drawable.chimpanzee,
        R.drawable.cow, R.drawable.crocodile,
        R.drawable.crow, R.drawable.doberman_pincher,
        R.drawable.dolphin, R.drawable.donkey,
        R.drawable.duck, R.drawable.elephant,
        R.drawable.goat, R.drawable.gorilla,
        R.drawable.hawk, R.drawable.horse,
        R.drawable.hound, R.drawable.lamb,
        R.drawable.lion, R.drawable.monkey,
        R.drawable.mosquito, R.drawable.nightingale,
        R.drawable.owl, R.drawable.peacock,
        R.drawable.penguin, R.drawable.rooster,
        R.drawable.sample_29
   };
   }
```

Can any one tell me what is wrong in it i have stored my images in drawable folder and sounds in asssets folder.

Comment: Did you get anything in logcat?

Comment: Did you get the toast message when clicking on an item?

Comment: yes, it displays tost with image number @Boss

Comment: put an else condition, check if `afd` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving Volume manually as in example below

```
  if(afd != null) {
                        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                        mp.start();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have short sound samples.then its better to use soundpool

```
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

 /** soundId for Later handling of sound pool **/ 
 int soundId = sp.load(context, R.raw.sample_sound, 1); // in 2nd param u have to pass your desire ringtone

 sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
   try{
       AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = AmbeMaAartiActivity.this.getAssets().openFd("myfile.mp3");
       m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength() );
       descriptor.close();
       m.prepare();
       m.start();
   } catch(Exception e){
       // handle error here.. 
   }`